# How to reboot a Raspberry Pi 5 minutes after shutdown?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, operating-system, boot

I want a simple script that **reboots** the raspberry pi itself 5 minutes after a voluntary shutdown programmatically using python. My script just reboots it immediately.

```
if temp > 70:
    os.system("sudo reboot")
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You want a python script running on another machine that _turns on_ the raspberry pi 5 minutes after it has been shut down?

Comment: Sorry the clarity. I want the same raspberry pi to reboot itself

Comment: Well - how should that work? If its down, it cant execute scripts. I doubt there is a "shutdown and reboot in 5mins" code. In linux you could do a `shutdown -t <addtimehere>` but that will **wait** the time and then shut down. SO has proven me wrong though, will see if anyone can come up with something to do this magic feat.

Comment: I deleted my answer. Realized that you probably dont want to restart every 5th minute all the time, just one time after your shutdown?

Comment: Just one time after after shutdown

Comment: Unfortunately, not possible, as pointed out

Comment: @PatrickArtner Have a look at my answer.... ( Developpers a oftenly called wizard! ;)

Comment: @F.Hauri will do

Comment: @F.Hauri ... waiting five minutes before shut-down is **not** the same as shutting down, and powering back up in 5 minutes.  Your answer is WRONG.

Comment: @tink You missread my answer: I stop everything immediately, than (re)boot after 5 minutes! This is very close than request!

Comment: Ummm ... stopping services is not the same as shutting it down.

Comment: @think Stopping to work make stop heating... So you'r right, but result is: system are cooling 5 minutes before *booting again*.

Comment: I found a solution

Answer (score 0):

## Nothing is impossible to a willing heart!

### How to continue to work once shutted off?

Ok, this is a strange question, as this seem clear that a system could not work once down....

But

- Programmable *system clock* could wake system at defined time. Unfortunely the *raspberry pi* don't have such kind of onboard timer system.

  But there are some samples/modules:

  - [Raspberry Pi Power Controller](https://www.susa.net/wordpress/2012/11/raspberry-pi-power-controller/)
  - [Raspberry Pi RTC: Adding a Real Time Clock](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-rtc/)
  - [Sleepy Pi (Power Management Shield for Raspberry Pi)](https://www.pishop.us/product/sleepy-pi-power-management-shield-raspberry-pi/)
- Second way: stopping all cpu heating services.

  If not totally down, a system without any service running become *quiet* enough for cooling.

  Under *Un*x*, when switched in *single user mode*, a system don't do anything (some raid sync could run anyway... If there is no raid on *raspberry pi*, you may have to care, maybe stop raid, wifi and/or unload some modules, before sleep then reboot).
- Third way: Electricaly cut power supply with discharging *default on* relay.

  you could create a little module with one small battery or capacitor and one 5V relay to cut power supply (when powered). When battery/capacitor become empty, or with a little timer, you could free relay, then power come back...

### Stopping all services and reboot 5' after

There is one thing you could do:

#### Disclaimer:  This is aproximate solution only, as I don't have free raspi now for doing the test and because this depend on distrib and version!! You have to **understand** what you do, then adapt some part of this!

- learn how *runlevel* work

  - runlevel 1 is single user mode
  - ... network mode ...
  - runlevel 5 is default normal mode
- copy `/etc/rc1.d/` to some unused of `/etc/rc[2..4].d/` (after saving them)

  ```
  mv /etc/rc2.d /etc/rc2.d-old
  cp -a /etc/rc1.d /etc/rc2.d
  ```

  note number of symlink used for running `single` script

  ```
  ls /etc/rc2.d/S*single
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 jun 19 18:04 /etc/rc2.d/S32single -> ../init.d/single
  ```

  drop them

  ```
  rm /etc/rc2.d/S32single
  ```

  create your own `/etc/init.d/rebootIn5`, by copying skeleton

  ```
  cp /etc/init.d/skeleton /etc/init.d/rebootIn5
  ```

  edit them to make `start` function contain something like

  ```
  nohup sh -c 'sleep $((5*60)) ; reboot' &
  ```

  maybe `init 5` instead of `reboot`, and checking termal value `while (( $(</sys/.../therm_input) > 50 ));do sleep 20;done` instead of `sleep 300`...

  Then link them to

  ```
  ln -s ../init.d/rebootIn5 rc2.d/S32rebootIn5
  ```
- call this by your script:

  ```
  if temp > 70:
      os.system("sudo init 2")
  ```

### See also...

It could by simplier to check for wich service are heating your system.
(command `top` could give quick overview)

```
top -bn 1 | sed '/^ *PID USER/,+1{//d;p};d'
```

then stop and restart only one or few services...

This could by done by switching between runlevel too. You have to configure on of rulevel `2` to `4` to stop all services you previously defined. Juste care that service *cron* don't become stopped.

Comment: Who downvoted this, and why!? This question is a strange but interesting challenge!

Comment: The question is interesting, the answer is "It can't be done".  Your solution doesn't do what he asked.

Comment: My answer offer 3 different way for immediately stop *heating*, than (re)boot after 5 min. This match the request!! Two way could do EXACTLY what request ask for!! And the third stop **everything** but system himself. This could do the job!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution using a systemd timer unit.  It's working for me.

```
# The quiesce-wait-reboot.timer target places system in rescue mode to quiesce all services 
#       and then waits for the above interval for the UPS to run out of battery and shutdown
#   If line power is restored and the UPS doesn't shutdown, the timer will expire and cause a reboot 
#
#   It should be started with "systemctl isolate quiesce-wait-reboot.timer"
#       by doing an isolate, all services not part of rescue.target will be shutdown
[Unit]
Description=Quiesce to Rescue Mode, Wait, then Reboot - addresses UPS race condition
Requires=rescue.target 
After=rescue.target
AllowIsolate=yes

[Timer]
OnActiveSec=900
Unit=reboot.target
```